# Add some text to Chrome address bar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a plugin for chrome. Plugin should add to the address bar some information, after the address. For example a small clarification. How can I change the text of the address bar? Does it possible at all?

Comment: what type of information you want too add?

Comment: For example date of last visit.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** if you change the address in the address bar the page will **get reloaded** if its not an #value.

Comment: Page will not reload either when `history.replaceState` of `history.pushState` is used (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState\(\).C2.A0method)). However, I think that the OP is using the wrong tool for the job: The address bar should only be used to display the location of the current page, *not* "a small clarification".

Comment: "if its not an #value."
What you mean?